# How to make TIFF from GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a lot of GeoTIFF images. However, as there is a mistake in the GeoTIFF tag, I am considering re-tagging.
Therefore, make GeoTIFF to TIFF after that re-tag from GDAL.

However, I don't know how to convert from GeoTIFF to TIFF.
How can I do this?

I tried using imagemagick's convert once, but it did not become TIFF.

```
convert input.tiff output.tiff
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 8):

Using the `PROFILE=BASELINE` creation option with [`gdal_translate`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) will strip the [GeoTIFF tags](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html):

```
gdal_translate -co PROFILE=BASELINE input.tif output.tif
```